# Getting RowCount For IQueryable not IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, reflection, automapper, iqueryable, open-closed-principle

Long story short, we have a C# WebApi that provides mapped instances from our DAL into DTOS.

Each controller exposes a `IEnumerable<T> Get()`

I have a test that finds all the controllers, and call this get method.

This flushes out any mapping errors that only occur on execution.

A while I noticed that to be sure you had to actually execute the enumeration otherwise the the mapping never takes place.

So I have this code

```
if (results is IEnumerable enumerable)
{
    var counter = enumerable.Cast<object>().Count();
    Trace.Write($"{counter} results found.");
}
```

This executes the cast (which invokes the mapping) and gives me a count for output reasons.

This worked until the result set got massive - it nows just times out.

Most of my IEnumerables are actually IQueryable underneath

I need a way to `Take(10)` on an IQueryable that can work on reflected data/executed types. This will let the mapping work but on a smaller data set.

Help!

Comment: You can use `Take` after `Cast`: `Cast<object>().Take(10).Count()` - only the first 10 objects will be counted. Of course, the `Count()` will always be no more than 10.